# Visual Studio 2012 crashes on build

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

My Visual Studio crashes when building a specific application, but not others. I work with several solutions with no problems, but when I try to work with this specific solution, VS crashes and is closed whenever I try to build it.

The same solution works on other people's machines.

How can I fix it?

The application is a MVC web app using Entity Framework, if it makes any difference.

My OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

**UPDATE:**

I found some logs that looks related to the crash.

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTIONS FROM PROCESS 11176:
=====================
24/04/2014 19:46:50
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveType> System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.GetPrimitiveTypes(Double)'.
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.MetadataExtensionMethods.GetPrimitiveTypes(EdmItemCollection itemCollection, Version edmVersion)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.ModelHelper.AllPrimitiveTypes(Version targetFrameworkVersion)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.Entity.FunctionImport.get_IsReturnTypeComplexType()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.Entity.FunctionImport.get_ReturnType()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.Entity.FunctionImport.<get_Children>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFContainer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFNormalizableItem.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFObject.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFContainer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFNormalizableItem.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFObject.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFContainer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFNormalizableItem.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFObject.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EntityDesignArtifact.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.Model.VSArtifact.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.EFObject.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.ModelManager.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.VisualStudioEdmxValidator.Finalize()
```

Comment: more info is needed... crash info what exception etc...

Comment: It does not give an error message, just gives me the generic Windows 'Application stopped working' dialog and then restarts it.

Comment: Are you using any custom/additional build steps?

Comment: No additional build steps.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all the files in the output folders (manually) and rebuild the solution?

Comment: Tried it now. Still crashes.

Comment: Have you tried re-adding references? Perhaps switching versions of the ones that usually come with multiple?

Comment: Maybe remove all packages regarding EF and reinstall them. You might want to check the underlying dataprovider (database/sql server) versions as well.

Comment: I've had the same problems building a website with a ton of symbols in an offline setting from time to time.  I go to debug the site and then VS 12 crashes asking me if I want to debug the debugger.  Keeping an eye on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted that my machine had an item called `Entity Framework Designer for Visual Studio 2012` on the Windows list of installed programs and none of the my colleagues had it.

I uninstalled it and then it builds.

**UPDATE:**

Obviously, I lost the ability to edit Entity models when I uninstalled the designer. Now Visual Studio opens it as XML. Not good.

It looks like all this mess was caused by Entity Framework CTP July 2011, which was installed in my machine. The problem was not caused by EF designer, but by the system being confused by multiple versions of EF assemblies.

This mix of EF versions caused some other problems, and trying to remove it caused some more.

Answer (score 1):

try remove bin and obj file -> rebuild project

Comment: Already tried it, got the same error.

Comment: ok, of course did you close vs, remove bin, obj, kill all processes from this app etc?